# If gravity is a fictitious force, how is it responsible for the spherical shape of planet?

Tags: gravity

If gravity isn’t acting directly on Earth’s mass how is it the cause of the Earth’s shape?

I often read that gravity "pulls" earth into its spherical shape, but if gravity is a fictitious force how can it "pull" on earth?

Comment: If the Coriolis force is a fictitious force, then how does it affect the paths of hurricanes?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509288/37364

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How fictitious are fictitious forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24338/how-fictitious-are-fictitious-forces)

Answer (score 1):

Fictitious forces are those that appear to arise as a consequence of the tendency of objects to move inertially. According to General Relativity, mass (and energy) bends spacetime, so that the paths of objects moving inertially are bent in a certain way. The bending effect has a spherical symmetry. The result is that the matter that makes up the Earth came together as a consequence of a local curvature in spacetime, the spherical symmetry of which caused the particles to form, and remain in, a roughly spherical shape. The Earth is slightly ellipsoid, bulging at the equator owing to the centrifugal effect of its rotation- ironically another fictitious force.