# Is magnetic force pseudo?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, reference-frames

Is magnetic force pseudo

Magnetic force exist only if charge is moving, so it must be pseudo.
Imagine, a positively charged man who has the same speed as electron (charge). So, he doesn't feel any magnetic force as charge is at rest with respect to him.
Therefore, he only experience electric force.

However a man who is at rest or has different speed than electron feels a magnetic force

Therefore magnetic force must be pseudo.
Pls answer me

Comment: Good thought, but not right. A pseudo force arises when you treat an accelerated frame of reference as inertial. This explains more about it. [Coriolis Force: Direction Perpendicular to Rotation Axis Visualization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/580812/37364)

Comment: Friction only exists if there's relative motion. Is friction a pseudoforce?

Comment: There are answers assuming different possible interpretations of your question, so I'll ask explicitly: by "pseudo" you mean a [fictitious force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) or an [axial vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector)?

Comment: Fictions force just like centrifugal and coriolis

Comment: Mr.Dandan0101 , I am very begginer in physics , pls don't reply rudely

Comment: Pseudoforces are _always_ proportional to the mass of the particle. Magnetic forces are not.

Comment: No pls explain in detail

Comment: Please do not repost questions you have already asked. If you are dissatisfied with the answers you have received to your earlier question you can a) offer a bounty for a better answer, explaining what you're missing in the current answers or b) ask a new question that *specifically* asks about what remained unclear to you. Why would you expect to get different answers by just posting the exact same question again?

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari He wasn't being rude, he was asking you a question to help you think careful about the situation

Answer (score 5):

No, the magnetic force is not a pseudo force.

1. all pseudo forces are proportional to the mass of the thing on which the force is acting, but the magnetic force is proportional to the charge.
2. all pseudo forces disappear in an inertial frame, but the magnetic force exists in an inertial frame

Answer (score 1):

Here is why the magnetic *field* is pseudo while the electric field is not: people assumed that under a physically-non-exist mirror flip, the charge remains its sign. That directly indicates that the electric field is vector while the magnetic field is pseudo. If people assume the magnetic monopole (which people haven't observed!) remains the sign after the mirror flip, then the magnetic field will be vector. These are just based on common-sense definitions. Being pseudo or not is just in different representations of the mirror symmetry.

Back to your question. The force is not pseudo, because both the magnetic field and the magnet or the monopole if existed will transform under the same representation and therefore the improper factor $(-1)^{\mathrm{det(rep)}}$ get multiplied twice which will give $1$.

Comment: You are discussing a topic that is not related to the question, namely the pseudovector nature of the magnetic field.

Comment: @my2cts if you have ever read through the whole answer I bet you probably won’t make such a comment.

Comment: @RoderickLee I understand the confusion since the question isn't very clear, but it appears to be asking if magnetic force is a pseudo force (perhaps better known as a fictitious force), not whether it is a pseudovector.

Answer (score 1):

I read sometime ago in a book (Purcell - Electricity and Magnetism ch. 5.6):

If you have an extense wire with net charge desnsity equal to zero in some referencial, i.e. its linear density $\rho_r = 0$, in such way: You have the positive charges non-moving but with some space between them and moving negative charges.

Suppose you have another charge in some point around the wire and it's at rest in this referential.

If you go to another referential, using relativity stuff, you can show that now you'll have a net charge density in the wire and it'll exerce a force in that charge that's quite equal the Magnetic force that shoub be acting (it's even proportional to the current).

Soo, you can understand magnetic force, in first approximation, as an "relativistic face" of the electric force.

I extremely recommend you to read the chapter I said above, I'm not good trying to explain such things.