# Magnetic force is pseudo?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, reference-frames

Is magnetic force pseudo

Magnetic force exist only if charge is moving , so it must be pseudo . Imagine , a positively charged man who has the same speed as electron (charge). So , he doesn't feel any magnetic force as charge is at rest with respect to him. Therefore , he only experience electric force .

However a man who is at rest or has different speed than electron feels a magnetic force

Therefore magnetic force must be pseudo. Pls answer me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is magnetic force pseudo](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/680990/)